# Discussion to deal with questions with "we don't know" answers?

Tags: discussion

It's been on my mind for a time but the thing that triggered this post is the closing of the question

> [Who beheaded the celestial that became knowhere?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93513/who-beheaded-the-celestial-that-became-knowhere)

as primarily opinion based by 5 members of the community.

[Another instance of a user VTC as primary opinion based](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93406/how-did-snape-allow-his-old-advanced-potions-book-to-be-used-by-harry?noredirect=1#comment157891_93406) was to the question

> [How did Snape allow his old advanced potions book to be used by Harry?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93406/how-did-snape-allow-his-old-advanced-potions-book-to-be-used-by-harry)

This question was, however, not closed by the community at large.

[A third instance of "we don't know" answer to a question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/92560/5315) was my favorite one so far because as it later turned out, there was in-fact canon answer if you just looked closer enough.

So, what should be done with current & future questions whose answered could potentially be "We don't know from the available canon so far"

Comment: Doesn't really depend on the answer rather than the question. Confusing those matters seems again like trying to solve an overgeneralized problem that might not be well-represented by the few examples picked for it. Could you elaborate a little in which way you see a discrepancy in the way those questions have been dealt with so far? Is it the POB closure of one of them?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson my issue is with people thinking "we don't know" answers make the question POB. I will write my detailed thoughts but in a while

Comment: Part of the issue is the way the closed question is worded.. "what do you think", was the comment AFAIR...just editing the question to ask for any movie based information solves the question's problem...without invalidating the answer (mine). I've done that and VTR.

Comment: Essentially SF&F had the same discussion for the same reasons - https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11329/are-answers-that-state-we-dont-know-acceptable

Comment: I think this problem should partially depend on if the in-universe of the Q, is still in some way ongoing. Like the 'How do the White Walker's raise the dead' Q, I'm pretty sure there isn't an answer "right now", but come season 8 or potentially the upcoming prequel series (The Long Night), this will probably address it more. Even the HP universe keeps expanding & there could be things that are directly addressed or might be suggested in supposition in upcoming material (Fantastic Beasts, Pottermore, tie-in materials). I agree that many jump 2 POB too soon on some of these.

Answer (score 1):

I see that this was a non-issue for most of the meta community.

**So, "We don't know" is a perfectly acceptable answer if worded according to [this brilliant answer from SFF.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11330/15706).**

For future reference, there can be two instances whose answers can be "we don't know"

1. If the event has already taken place, a question about that event is on-topic and can have "we don't know" answer.
   ex. Did *spoiler* get snapped?
2. If the event has not taken place and is expected in the future, a question about that event is off-topic (primarily opinion based) because its answer will be "we don't know".
   ex. How will *spoiler* who's stranded on *spoiler* planet get back to Earth?